# Custom error message in pyramid jsonrpc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, json-rpc

I have an application written with pyramid_rpc. We call our functions over the net via json_rpc. Some times there is an error in user input (logical error) and I want to return an custom error to user. for example consider this part of code:

```
@jsonrpc_method(method='calc.insurance.fee', endpoint="api")
def market_engine_beta(request, person_id: int, age: int):    
    if age < 10:        
        raise ValueError('age should be bigger than 10')
```

but when I call the method with age=8 I see this error:
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "error": {"message": "internal error", "code": -32603}}

how could I return my error to the user?
note:
I also tried this link: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/views.html#custom-exception-views

Answer (score 1):

You can raise a [`JsonRpcError`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_rpc/en/latest/jsonrpc.html#pyramid_rpc.jsonrpc.JsonRpcError); if you included `pyramid_rpc` with [`config.include`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_rpc/en/latest/jsonrpc.html#setup), there should be a custom exception view that would handle these correctly.

For your custom exceptions having a custom view should work; however it is important to ensure that the code is indeed correct and doesn't result in additional exceptions being thrown.